# Java replaceAll ' with '' except first and last occurrence

Tags: java, replaceall

I want to replace all occurrences of single quotations with two quotations, except in first and last occurrence, I managed to get to exclude the last occurrence using regex as follows

```
String toReplace = "'123'456'";
String regex = "'(?=.*')";
String replaced = toReplace.replaceAll(regex,"''");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Here I get

```
''123''456'
```

How do I get

```
'123''456'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to escape the value for SQL?

Comment: Maybe you can replace all single quotations with two and after that remove first and last single quations?

Comment: How about `replaced.substring(0,1)` remove the first character because you already stated you excluded the last char

Comment: @kayaman yes I am string to escape for sql

Comment: @Meesh then stop what you're doing. Escaping values manually is useless, and using regex to do it is complicated and useless. Use `PreparedStatement.setString()` and it will escape everything necessary. Then you don't need the `'` in the beginning and end either.

Comment: @kayaman thank you for that I will continue on that path

Comment: @Meesh great! There are plenty of examples to be found on SO if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pithy saying about regular expressions and [two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/), but I'll skip that and suggest you simplify this by using a `StringBuilder`; find the index of both the first `'` and the last `'` in your input, then iterate between those indices looking for `'` (and replacing with `''`). Something like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(toReplace);
int first = toReplace.indexOf("'"), last = toReplace.lastIndexOf("'");
if (first != last) {
    for (int i = first + 1; i < last; i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == '\'') {
            sb.insert(i, '\'');
            i++;
        }
    }
}
toReplace = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
int first = toReplace.indexOf("'") + 1;
int last = toReplace.lastIndexOf("'");

String afterReplace = toReplace.substring(0, first)
        + toReplace.substring( first,last ).replaceAll("'", "''")
        + toReplace.substring(last);

System.out.println(afterReplace);
```

With `StringBuilder`

```java
String afterReplace = new StringBuilder()
        .append(toReplace, 0, first)
        .append(toReplace.substring(first, last).replaceAll("'", "''"))
        .append(toReplace, last, toReplace.length())
        .toString();
```

Or with `String.format`

```java
String afterReplace = String.format("%s%s%s",
        toReplace.substring(0, first),
        toReplace.substring(first, last).replaceAll("'", "''"),
        toReplace.substring(last));
```

Comment: Avoid string concatenation, use StringBuilder.add instead. Good solution

Comment: For this I don't see any problem using string concatenation, using StringBuilder here is a premature optimization I guess.

Comment: Right, @RuelosJoel, may be I hate too much string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

**Regex expression:** (?<=')(. *)(?=')

> It will help you to find out your result and then you can replace it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with regex as well:

```
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "'123'456'";
      String pattern = "(?>^')(.*)(?>'$)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         String replaced = m.group(1).replaceAll("'","\"");
         System.out.println("replaced value: " + replaced );
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
```